# postgresql execute dynamic sql command

Tags: postgresql

I'm slowly learning more about PostgreSQL, as we are attempting to move to it from MSSQL Server.

In MSSQL I have the following code:

```
DECLARE ServiceabilityParameters 
CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY STATIC LOCAL FOR
SELECT  WorkbookParameterType.ID, 
        WorkbookParameterType.Name, 
        WorkbookParameter.DefaultValue,  
        WorkbookParameter.CommandText
FROM    WorkbookParameter
JOIN    WorkbookParameterType ON WorkbookParameterType.ID = WorkbookParameter.WorkbookParameterTypeID
JOIN    WorkbookParameterDirectionType ON WorkbookParameterDirectionType.ID = WorkbookParameter.WorkbookParameterDirectionTypeID
AND                                       WorkbookParameterDirectionType.Writable = 1
WHERE   WorkbookParameter.WorkbookID = @WorkbookID

OPEN ServiceabilityParameters

FETCH NEXT FROM ServiceabilityParameters INTO @WorkbookParameterTypeID, @WorkbookParameterTypeName, @WorkbookDefaultValue, @WorkbookCommandText

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
DECLARE @ActualValue        NVARCHAR(256) = NULL    

IF @WorkbookCommandText IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql  @statement              = @WorkbookCommandText, 
                        @params                 = N'@ApplicationContainerID INT, @Value NVARCHAR(256) OUTPUT', 
                        @ApplicationContainerID = @ApplicationContainerID,
                        @Value                  = @ActualValue OUTPUT
END

IF @ActualValue IS NULL AND @WorkbookDefaultValue IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ActualValue = @WorkbookDefaultValue
END

INSERT  @InputParameters (
    ID, Name, Value
) VALUES (
    @WorkbookParameterTypeID, @WorkbookParameterTypeName, @ActualValue
)

FETCH NEXT FROM ServiceabilityParameters INTO @WorkbookParameterTypeID, @WorkbookParameterTypeName, @WorkbookDefaultValue, @WorkbookCommandText
END

CLOSE ServiceabilityParameters
DEALLOCATE ServiceabilityParameters
```

I'm trying to work out how to do the sp_executesql part in a PostgreSQL function. I believe that I can do the rest, but most of the examples that I have found show a simple select with maybe a few variables, whereas I need to execute another function, with parameters, where the function name is text in a table.

Many Thanks.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to execute a function with parameters

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT Value FROM ' || v_workbookCommandText || '(ApplicationContainerID :=$1)'
INTO v_actualValue
USING v_applicationContainerID;
```

In case you need select records a function, you can using INOUT refcursor variable

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT Value FROM ' || v_workbookCommandText || '(ApplicationContainerID :=$1, refcur:= $2)'
INTO v_actualValue
USING v_applicationContainerID, my_cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is `EXECUTE 'some string'`, like [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html):

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE inserted_by = $1 AND inserted <= $2'
   INTO c
   USING checked_user, checked_date;
```

Another option is to create and use your own [PL/PGSQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html).

Comment: Not really ... unless 'some string' can be the name of another function with parameters ... but cheers anyway.